# Error when using 'create-react-native-app'

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, expo

I tried to create a new React Native app using the command `create-react-native-app` in the node.js terminal on my Windows system. I got the following terminal error:

```
D:\project>create-react-native-app crna
Creating a new React Native app in D:\project\crna.

Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.
Installing react-native-scripts...

npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Suppor
t
npm WARN deprecated @exponent/spawn-async@1.2.8: Please switch to @expo/spawn-as
ync, the new name of this package. It's the same code with our new name.
npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\ui-admin\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-3204-a
eacedd1\registry.npmjs.org\_40exponent\ngrok\-\ngrok-2.2.7.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 37fe66f922b1003da2a78c66b7d4d3bc9313e423
npm ERR! Actual:   d134060eb730b880da06d5c040ca933f6a75b613
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/@exponent/ngrok/-/ngrok-2.2.7.tgz

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ui-admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-05-26T09_36_
04_379Z-debug.log
`npm install --save-dev --save-exact react-native-scripts` failed
```

Anyone met this error or fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, though in RubyMine, which provided the response that react-native doesn't work with npm 5 yet. it said you can either revert to npm 4 or feel free to log an issue here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16991

I think you're best bet would be to revert and wait it out!

Comment: Yeah!

Create React Native App doesn't work with npm 5 yet, unfortunately. They
recommend using npm 4 or yarn until some bugs are resolved.